# Solving equations of the form $x^n+a=0$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

I was wondering if there is a quick method to find all solutions to equations of the form $x^n+a=0$. In many cases I have seen solutions to such equations to be nth roots multiplied by nth roots of unity, what is the general method to solve such problems?

Comment: That's precisely the general method

Comment: If $a$ is positive, you multiply by the roots of minus unity.

Comment: If you’re having lots of difficulty, consider values of $a$ such as $1$ and $2$. Ask yourself, “How do I solve this?” Then expand it for any value $a$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$x^n+a=0 \implies x^n=-a \implies x=\zeta_n\sqrt[n]{-a}$ where $n=0,1, \dots, n-1$. Here, $\zeta_n$ is the primitive $n$-th root of unity you're talking about in your question.